# Set distance of THREE.PerspectiveCamera without change view direction

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

I have `PerspectiveCamera` in THREE.js somewhere in space as children of mesh. The camera should still look at the mesh (local coordinates [0, 0, 0]). I would like to change distance of camera from the mesh without change of view direction. Is there any easy way to do this?

```
camera.position.z = 13 // Works only if position.x and position.y are 0.
camera.setDistanceFromTarget(13) // I need something like this.
```

I just thinking about manual calculation of the actual camera's rotation angles and new camera's position. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u5t1wqo/18/).

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
scene.add(cube);
cube.add(camera);

camera.position.set(2, 4, 6)
camera.lookAt(cube.position)

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();

// How to set distance of camera from [0, 0, 0] to 13 without change view direction?
camera.position.z = 13;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>THREE.js camera demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the camera is at x, y, z, then the current distance is `Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)`. Take each coordinate, multiply it by the new distance, then divide it by the calculated distance. (this works because the camera is looking at the origin; to move it back in general you need to add a negative multiple of its view vector to its position)

Comment: `camera.position.setLength(13)` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [normalize](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.normalize) the camera position vector, and then [scalarly multiply](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.multiplyScalar) it by the desired length:

```
camera.position.normalize().multiplyScalar(13)
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/0jnw5guo/ ]